# how to change language for DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I store, in a session variable, which language does user wants to translate but I don't know to pass it DataTables

I found [this explanation on the datatables website](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/language_file.html) but that didn't really help, where do I set language param ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You have to either create a language file and then set it using :

```
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "media/language/your_file.txt"
}
```

Im not sure what server language you are using but something like this would work in PHP :

```
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "media/language/custom_lang_<?php echo $language ?>.txt"
}
```

Where `language` matches the file name for a specific language.

or change individual settings :

```
"oLanguage": {
  "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
  "sZeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
  "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
  "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 records",
  "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
}
```

For more details read this : http://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n

Comment: oh nice!! u can try other language `"oLanguage": { "sUrl": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/<LANGUAGE>.json" }` a open https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/ and look translation is click ur language later take CDN links :)

Comment: This does not seem to work any more in 1.10.19. It is `language` instead of `oLanguage` and `url` instead of `sUrl`. See the posts below. These worked for me.

Answer (score 44):

```
//Spanish
$('#TableName').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "sProcessing":    "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":    "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":   "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":    "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":          "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":     "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":  "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":   "",
        "sSearch":        "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":           "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":    "Último",
            "sNext":    "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
    }
});
```

Also using a cdn:

```
//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/i18n/Spanish.json
```

More options: http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/English [| Spanish | etc]

Answer (score 17):

sorry to revive this thread, i know there is the solution, but it is easy to change the language with the datatables. Here, i leave you with my own datatable example.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
// DataTable
        var table = $('#tblUsuarios').DataTable({
            aoColumnDefs: [
                {"aTargets": [0], "bSortable": true},
                {"aTargets": [2], "asSorting": ["asc"], "bSortable": true},
            ],
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
            }

    });
```

The language you get from the following link:

http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n

Just replace the URL value in the language option with the one you like.
Remember to always use the comma

---

Worked for me, hope it will work for anyone.

Best regards!

Answer (score 9):

for Arabic language

```
 var table = $('#my_table')
                .DataTable({
                 "columns":{//......}
                 "language": 
                        {
                            "sProcessing": "جارٍ التحميل...",
                            "sLengthMenu": "أظهر _MENU_ مدخلات",
                            "sZeroRecords": "لم يعثر على أية سجلات",
                            "sInfo": "إظهار _START_ إلى _END_ من أصل _TOTAL_ مدخل",
                            "sInfoEmpty": "يعرض 0 إلى 0 من أصل 0 سجل",
                            "sInfoFiltered": "(منتقاة من مجموع _MAX_ مُدخل)",
                            "sInfoPostFix": "",
                            "sSearch": "ابحث:",
                            "sUrl": "",
                            "oPaginate": {
                                "sFirst": "الأول",
                                "sPrevious": "السابق",
                                "sNext": "التالي",
                                "sLast": "الأخير"
                            }
                        }
                });
```

Ref: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Arabic

Author: Ossama Khayat

Comment: Hi Basheer, I added exactly this, but it did not work, I am using 1.10.20 version of DataTables

Answer (score 7):

French translations:

```
$('#my_table').DataTable({
  "language": {
    "sProcessing": "Traitement en cours ...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ lignes",
    "sZeroRecords": "Aucun résultat trouvé",
    "sEmptyTable": "Aucune donnée disponible",
    "sInfo": "Lignes _START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Aucune ligne affichée",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrer un maximum de_MAX_)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sSearch": "Chercher:",
    "sUrl": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement...",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst": "Premier", "sLast": "Dernier", "sNext": "Suivant", "sPrevious": "Précédent"
    },
    "oAria": {
      "sSortAscending": ": Trier par ordre croissant", "sSortDescending": ": Trier par ordre décroissant"
    }
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 6):

There are language files uploaded in a CDN on the dataTables website https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/  So you only have to replace "Spanish" with whatever language you are using in the following example.

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Spanish

```
$('table.dataTable').DataTable( {
    language: {
        url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json'
    }
});
```

Comment: For me this only worked with the "https:" prefix: `language: {
        url: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json'
    }`

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that you have to exactly specify your path to your language.JSON like this:

```
language: {
    url: '/mywebsite/js/localisation/German.json'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed

```
language: {
 url: '//URL_TO_CDN'
}
```

The problem is not all of the DataTables (As of this writing) are valid JSON. The Traditional Chinese file for instance is one of them.

To get around this I wrote the following code in JavaScript:

```
  var dataTableLanguages = {
    'es': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json',
    'fr': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/French.json',
    'ar': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Arabic.json',
    'zh-TW': {
      "processing": "處理中...",
      "loadingRecords": "載入中...",
      "lengthMenu": "顯示 _MENU_ 項結果",
      "zeroRecords": "沒有符合的結果",
      "info": "顯示第 _START_ 至 _END_ 項結果，共 _TOTAL_ 項",
      "infoEmpty": "顯示第 0 至 0 項結果，共 0 項",
      "infoFiltered": "(從 _MAX_ 項結果中過濾)",
      "infoPostFix": "",
      "search": "搜尋:",
      "paginate": {
        "first": "第一頁",
        "previous": "上一頁",
        "next": "下一頁",
        "last": "最後一頁"
      },
      "aria": {
        "sortAscending": ": 升冪排列",
        "sortDescending": ": 降冪排列"
      }
    }
  };
  var language = dataTableLanguages[$('html').attr('lang')];

  var opts = {...};
  
  if (language) {
    if (typeof language === 'string') {
       opts.language = {
         url: language
       };
    } else {
       opts.language = language;
    }
  }
```

Now use the opts as option object for data table like

```
$('#list-table').DataTable(opts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tradução para Português Brasil

```
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "sProcessing":    "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":    "Exibir _MENU_ registros por página",
        "sZeroRecords":   "Nenhum resultado encontrado",
        "sEmptyTable":    "Nenhum resultado encontrado",
        "sInfo":          "Exibindo do _START_ até _END_ de um total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":     "Exibindo do 0 até 0 de um total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":  "(Filtrado de um total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":   "",
        "sSearch":        "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":           "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":    "Último",
            "sNext":    "Próximo",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Ativar para ordenar a columna de maneira ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Ativar para ordenar a columna de maneira descendente"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular and Firebase, you can also use the DTOptionsBuilder :

```
angular.module('your_module', [
'ui.router',
'oc.lazyLoad',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ngSanitize',
'firebase']).controller("your_controller", function ($scope, $firebaseArray, DTOptionsBuilder) {

var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("your_database_table");

// create a synchronized array
$scope.your_database_table = $firebaseArray(ref);

ref.on('value', snap => {

    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withOption('language',
        {
            "sProcessing": "Traitement en cours...",
            "sSearch": "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
            "sLengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            "sInfo": "Affichage de l'&eacute;l&eacute;ment _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Affichage de l'&eacute;l&eacute;ment 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ment",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement en cours...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
            "sEmptyTable": "Aucune donn&eacute;e disponible dans le tableau",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Premier",
                "sPrevious": "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
                "sNext": "Suivant",
                "sLast": "Dernier"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
                "sSortDescending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre d&eacute;croissant"
            }
        }
        )

});})
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Make new copy from file **table.js** on `js\custom\apps\user-management\users\list` and rename it to **tableAr.js** here in this file **tableAr.js** you can change English text to Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

**for lao language**

```
"oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": "ຍັງບໍ່ມີຂໍ້ມູນ",
    "sLengthMenu": "ສະແດງ _MENU_ ແຖວຕໍ່ຫນ້າ",
    "sZeroRecords": "ບໍ່ພົບຂໍ້ມູນໃດໆ",
    "sInfo": "ສະແດງ _START_ ຫາ _END_ ຈາກ _TOTAL_ ແຖວ",
    "sInfoEmpty": "ສະແດງ 0 ຫາ 0 ຈາກ 0 ແຖວ",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(ກັ່ນຕອງຈາກ _MAX_ ບັນທຶກທັງໝົດ)"
}
```