# How to change language for DataTable passing javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, pentaho

[how to change language for DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342494/how-to-change-language-for-datatable?rq=1)
We could use following code from the server end.

```
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "media/language/custom_lang_<?php echo $language ?>.txt"
}
```

Now I am using data table inside pentaho. I don't have access to the server side code. 
Is it possible to change the url dynamically using a java script variable ?
The following script is not working as the code is converted to a string.

```
if(locale=='sv'){
    return {"url": "/pentaho/api/repos/pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/rinjan/messages_sv.json"};
}else{
    return {"url": "/pentaho/api/repos/pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/rinjan/messages_ge.json"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you use the Table Component that is built upon DataTable. It gets a property oLanguage that you could initialize it in the postexecution of the component by issuing an ajax request for fetching the json file corresponding to the language you wish.

The property oLanguage just expects the content of the language file in json format : you can try it by copying the content of a language file from there :
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/

Comment: Seems like this will work. Thanks. I will test and mark the solution