# DataTable not applying language directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatable to display a report. I want the table to be translated in italian so I followed the documentation and ended up with the following code.

```
$('#report').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "query_results.php?q=<?php echo $id_form; ?>",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "language":{
                "EmptyTable":     "Nessun dato presente nella tabella",
                "Info":           "Vista da _START_ a _END_ di _TOTAL_ elementi",
                "InfoEmpty":      "Vista da 0 a 0 di 0 elementi",
                "InfoFiltered":   "(filtrati da _MAX_ elementi totali)",
                "InfoPostFix":    "",
                "InfoThousands":  ".",
                "LengthMenu":     "Visualizza _MENU_ elementi",
                "LoadingRecords": "Caricamento...",
                "Processing":     "Elaborazione...",
                "Search":         "Cerca:",
                "ZeroRecords":    "La ricerca non ha portato alcun risultato.",
                "Paginate": {
                    "First":      "Inizio",
                    "Previous":   "Precedente",
                    "Next":       "Successivo",
                    "Last":       "Fine"
                },
                "Aria": {
                    "SortAscending":  ": attiva per ordinare la colonna in ordine crescente",
                    "SortDescending": ": attiva per ordinare la colonna in ordine decrescente"
                }
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {extend: 'copy', text: '<i class=" fa fa-clipboard"></i> Copia', className: 'standard-button btn btn-small'}, 
                {extend: 'excelHtml5', text: '<i class=" fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>  Excel', className: 'standard-button btn btn-small'},
                {extend: 'pdfHtml5', text: '<i class=" fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>  Pdf', className: 'standard-button btn btn-small'},
                {text: '<i class=" fa fa-refresh"></i> Aggiorna', action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {dt.ajax.reload();}, className: 'standard-button btn btn-small'},
                {text: '<i class=" fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Indietro', action: function( e, dt, node, config ){location.href = "/smartform/index.php";}, className: 'standard-button btn btn-small'}
            ],
            "columns": [
                <?php
                $stringa='';
                foreach($colonne_form as $colonna_form){
                    $stringa .= '{ "data": "'.$colonna_form['nome'].'"},';
                }
                echo rtrim($stringa,',');
                ?>
            ],
            //"deferRend" : true,
            //"processing": true,
            //fixedHeader: true,
            //responsive: true
        });
```

Everything works fine, table and buttons are correctly displayed, data are correctly loaded, but the labels are still in english. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tags inside the "language" tag are different.

Please refer to this topic [how to change language for DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342494/how-to-change-language-for-datatable)

Comment: you where right, i missed the s/o prefix. Thanks!

Comment: @LelioFaieta - Those labels with `s` or `o` prefixes are legacy values, from an older version of DataTables. Assuming you are using DataTables 1.10.x, you should use the updated labels. See [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) for an example. As you have seen, however, the newer versions of DataTables have backwards compatibility with the older labels. This is useful when you try to use a [language file](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/) which may not have been updated to use the new labels.

Comment: @LelioFaieta - In your case, I think your original labels in your question only needed to be adjusted to start with lowercase letters ( for example, `emptyTable` instead of `EmptyTable`).